# How can I structure this quicksort to stop quicksorting at a specific index value and start selection sorting?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a quicksort that works, and a selection sort that also works- I want to sort an `int[]` of random ints with quicksort up until the `array.length = 1` and then for that last element call selection sort. I know I need to have a conditional that checks the `array.length` and when `length = 1` then, return `selectionSort()` Im not sure how to structure it in the recursive calls within `quickSort()`. Here are my two sorting methods:

QuickSort:

```
public void quickSort(int array[], int start, int end) {
    int i = start; // index val of left-to-right scan
    int k = end; // index val of right-to-left scan

    if (end - start >= 1){
        PIVOT = array[start]; 
        while (k > i){
            while (array[i] <= PIVOT && i <= end && k > i)
                i++; 
            while (array[k] > PIVOT && k >= start && k >= i)
                k--;
            if (k > i) 
                swap(array, i, k); 
        }
        swap(array, start, k); 
        quickSort(array, start, k - 1); 
        System.out.println(k);
        quickSort(array, k + 1, end); 

    }
    return;
}
```

Selection Sort:

```
public void selectionSort(int[] nums) {
    //nums[0] = array[0];
    System.out.println(nums.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < (nums.length - 1); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[i] > nums[j]) {
                int temp = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[j];
                nums[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already almost doing it. With this line, `end - start` you're getting the length. If that length is less than your `SelectionSortThreshold`, run insertion sort **only on the current length**. This means modifying your `selectionSort` routine to accept a `start` and `end` parameter so that you can selection sort only a small portion of the array.

Comment: Where does he mention a threshold? Or is it implied? All I see is when array length is 1. Which would obviously be wrong because why would you try and sort a single item array...

Comment: @steven - because that is where there is too much overhead in the recursive calls of quicksort, its not wrong, but thanks for the comment.

Comment: @mcG73 Steven's point would be that sorting a one-element array isn't a useful ocupation, because it is already sorted. Your threshold should be some number larger than 1.

Comment: Yes, Steven is right. I do imply a threshold (I recommend 7 as a good starting place, but go ahead and experiment). There is ZERO point in calling a sort on a single element subarray - it is guaranteed to be sorted.